# Jinja Alphabetically sort a list with mixed case

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to sort the options in a select list alphabetically using Jinja filters. the problem I am having is the list has mixed case values and it is not coming out alphabetically. I would still like to continue using the jinja filter wondering if anyway to make it compare by lower case or something.

The list in its current form

- All Source Types
- Android Market
- Facebook
- Forums
- RSS Feeds
- Twitter
- YouTube
- iTunes

Jinja Code

```
{% for source,number in sources.items()|sort %}
        <option {% if number == user.postfiltertype %} selected {% endif %} value='{{ number }}'>{{ source }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Input

```
[('iTunes', 8), ('RSS Feeds', 2), ('Twitter Incoming', 9), ('Facebook', 4), ('Android Market', 10), ('All Source Types', 0), ('YouTube', 5), ('Twitter', 3), ('Forums', 1)]
```

Comment: you don't want to write your own filter? it's pretty simple to do.  and your function could just use the internal sort that uses a key function that converts the string to uppercase/lowercase and compares

Comment: I mean I could just seeing if Jinja could do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following after `|sort` :

```
(case_sensitive=False)
```

So you get:

```
{% for source,number in sources.items()|sort(case_sensitive=False) %}
```

See:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#filters

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the Jinja API and didn't see anything for that. That said, it would be relatively simple to do.  If you only wanted to convert the first item to lowercase, you could do:

```
def ignore_first_case(x):
    if len(x) >= 1 and not isinstance(x, str):
        return (hasattr(x[0], "lower") and x[0].lower() or x[0]) + x[1:]
    else:
        return hasattr(x, "lower") and x.lower() or x

def ignore_case_sort(seq):
    return seq.sort(key=ignore_first_case)
```

And then finally, you need to register it with the jinja environment

```
environment.filters["ignore_case_sort"] = ignore_case_sort
```